# how to enable try Face ID again button in alert when Face ID failed to authenticate in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, face-id

I am using Face id in my iOS app. Be default when user fails to authenticate try again not working. I want to add callback when user click on try again.Please see my below code.I have searched a lot but nothing found about face id.

```
func startFaceIDTest(){
        attempted = true
        if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
            let reason = "Identify yourself!"

            context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) {
                [unowned self] (successfaceID, authenticationError) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if successfaceID {
                        self.success = true
                        //self.unlockSecretMessage()
                    } else {
                        self.success = false

//                        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Authentication failed", message: "You could not be verified; please try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
//                        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
//                        self.present(ac, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if let err = error {
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    self.success = false
                    switch err.code {
                    case LAError.Code.biometryNotEnrolled.rawValue:
                        notifyUser("Your device not enrolled for biometric",
                                   err: err.localizedDescription)

                    case LAError.Code.passcodeNotSet.rawValue:
                        notifyUser("A passcode has not been set",
                                   err: err.localizedDescription)

                    case LAError.Code.biometryNotAvailable.rawValue:
                        notifyUser("Biometric authentication not available",
                                   err: err.localizedDescription)

                    default:
                        notifyUser("Unknown error",
                                   err: err.localizedDescription)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: notifyUser ... ?

Comment: it is just alert showing message